# Error in Import psutill - Python ver-2.7.7 psutil ver-2.1.3

Tags: python

I am trying to import psutil on python and this is what i get:

```
Python 2.7.7 (v2.7.7:f89216059edf, May 31 2014, 12:53:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 148, in <module>
    import psutil._psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 29, in <module>
    cext.TCPS_ESTABLISHED: _common.CONN_ESTABLISHED,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TCPS_ESTABLISHED'
```

Comment: Have you tried [the solution presented here](http://mykzilla.blogspot.com/2013/08/fixing-this-mornings-mach-os-x-psutil.html)?

Comment: Yes i have but since it is was not installed using GIT it's not relevant, psutil was installed using PIP

Comment: I was suggesting reinstalling it from git.

Comment: You can reinstall it by asking pip to install a specific release of `psutil`: `pip install psutil==2.1.3`